# Согласование: "XV - начала XVIII век(а/ов)"

Tags: согласование

1. XV - начала XVIII века
2. XV - начала XVIII веков

Какой вариант правильный?

Comment: Спасибо большое!

Answer (score 2):

Что-то происходило в течение всего этого периода, соответственно это были события XV - начала XVIII век**ов**. На письме историки сокращают до *XV - нач. XVIII вв.*

Comment: Спасибо большое!